# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a los proyetos deployados en mi localhost (JBOSS/ECLIPSE)?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, jboss

escribo para pedirles su orientación sobre cómo puedo hacer públicos los proyectos que deployo desde Eclipse en un servidor JBOSS local. Esto para poder acceder al proyecto deployado desde otro equipo. De antemano les agradezco cualquier comentario que puedan brindarme. Gracias!

Comment: Si haces un deployment en el equipo local A puedes acceder con la ip del equipo A desde un Equipo B, lo unico que debes hacer es habilitar los puertos de escucha en el firewall, la petición quedaria `http://ip_equipo_A:puerto/Context/...`, ahora si lo que deseas es ponerlos en internet entonces debes: Poner tu equipo en internet a traves de ip pública o desplegar en un hosting con el servidor de aplicaciones que requiere.

Comment: Muchas gracias, pude resolverlo con hacer la habilitación del puerto en el firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo de esta dos maneras al menos.

- La primera de ella es acceder al panel de administrador de la plataforma y buscar la  pestaña deployment

[image: administrador wildfly]

- La otra opción sería a través del terminal. Accedes a la carpeta donde esta instalado el servidor, de allí a la ruta donte esta una carpeta llamada standalone y finalmente deployments que es el lugar donde se guarda todos los archivos desplegables y escaneados por el server.

Ejm: /opt/wildfly-12.0.0.Final/standalone/deployments